# Parent element is ready before its child - Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

**This question had been modified to match the actual problem.**

*The original question mistakingly focused on iron-ajax, please see the original problem below. The question should have been:*

Please advice why child iron-ajax element is not ready during the 'ready' callback of my-component defined as follows:

```
<dom-module id="my-component">
    <template>
        <link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
        <iron-ajax
            id="selectionLoader"
            url=""
            method="GET"
            handle-as="json"
            debounce-duration="300"
            last-response="{{ suggestedOptions }}"
            last-error="{{ lastError }}"
            verbose=true
        >
        </iron-ajax>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    (function () {
        Polymer({
            is : 'paper-select',
            ready : function() {
                console.log(this.$.selectionLoader.generateRequest); // undefined
            }
        })
    })()
</script>
```

**Original question**

*Original title: 'WebComponentsReady' fires before iron-ajax ready - Polymer 1.0*

I need to assign some values to an observed property of a custom component that internally uses iron-ajax with disabled auto - so I need to call .generateRequest on the iron-ajax element. This should happen when host page/component is ready, in order to fetch from the server some defaults based on data in the host component code.

selected is an array property on the component observed like this:

```
observers: [
    '_selectedChanged(selected.splices)' // _selectedChanged calls .generateRequest
]
```

The observer is triggered by:

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    document.querySelector('paper-select').selected = [{id : 11855},{id : 11856}];
});
```

The problem is that WebComponentsReady fires before .generateRequest is available on the iron-ajax. So my component is initialized, _selectedChanged is called, but iron-ajax inside it is missing the method and in fact other properties/methods as well.

I've implemented a "deferred" workaround using setTimeout inside the component and it works like charm but it's obviously not the way. Also everything works if the observer is triggered some time later after the page load, e.g. by user's typing. This shows that the logic works, it's just the timing that is wrong.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can u not dispatch "generaterequest()" when polymer element is ready? Don't worry about observer at all.

Comment: 'ready' fires before 'WebComponentsReady', and iron-ajax doesn't have its properties yet at that time

Comment: Can u extend iron-ajax , adding to its "ready" an event . Then , back in your elements observables .... onReady-ironajax() .. generate the request there.

Comment: custom elements can't currently be extended. i would need to encapsulate it in some custom-iron-ajax which would contain the original iron-ajax, facing the same exact issue. to do what you propose I must go into iron-ajax SOURCE and fire an external ready event out of it. I thought elements would fire 'ready' to host by default but they don't. the weird thing is that the docs (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html) say 'The ready callback is called on any local DOM children before it’s called on the host element.', but it just doesn't seem to be so.

Comment: down to guesses now... when you instantiate the built-in iron-ajax, is it possible to pass in a CallBack function among the options list where CB includes the 'fire-event' that you would need to indicate iron-ajax is 'ready' . Then do.generateRequest()..

Comment: I don't instanciate it, it's  part of the template. Anyway I found the problem and it's not related to iron-ajax, posting my answer. @RobertRowntree thanks for trying. It wouldn't be possible without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue was having the html imports inside my component's <template>. 
The 'wrong' order of events makes sense as iron-ajax is not even registered at the time when its host calls the 'ready' callback.

I've moved the imports outside <dom-module> and now everything works as expected.