# why is my polymer parent component ready before the child

Tags: templates, polymer, lifecycle, ready

Contrary to polymer's documentation stating that polymer children components will become ready before parents, I can see in my code that the root-component's ready() method is being called before the main-box (child) code ready() method is being called.  The output is "root ready, main ready".  When I comment out the conditional template in root-component (the dom-if template) then I get "main ready, root ready".  I don't know why this is.  utk variable is currently hard coded to true, so it's not like the root-component appeared at a later time.

I have an index.html which has scripts and a tight little body:

```
    <body>
       <root-component></root-component>
    </body>
```

Root-component was a large polymer component until I stripped it down to understand where the issue lies:

```
    <dom-module id="root-component">
       <template>
         <template is="dom-if" if={{utk}}> <--- UNCOMMENT THIS INNER TEMPLATE TAG AND ITS END TAG AND YOU WILL SEE main-section-box IS READY BEFORE root-component
           <main-box></main-box>
         </template>
       </template>
      <script> 
         // defines polymer root-component here, defines utk property as true, ready method prints out "root ready" 
      </script>
    </dom-module>
```

And finally a main-box, which just prints out "HI":

```
    <dom-module id="main-box">
      <template>HI</template>
      <script> 
         // defs polymer main-box here, ready method prints out "main ready"
      </script>
    </dom-module>
```

Please help me understand why this is happening.

I am trying to determine when children are ready so I can fire a signal to them at a time when they're paying attention (don't want them to miss the signal), but since it appears that the root is becoming ready before the children, relying on ready() might not be as reliable as I thought.

Note, this question is distinct from [Parent element is ready before its child - Polymer 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347856/parent-element-is-ready-before-its-child-polymer-1-0).

Comment: Anything inside `dom-repeat` or `dom-if` is dynamically created. Better keep signal  firing in `attached`. Even for non-dynamically created elements, you may not find your element in `ready` callback of parent.

Comment: @a1626 so when parent.attached() is called, the children can accept signals?

Comment: in short, yes children can accept the signal.